# Linq to SQL create table

Tags: .net, wpf, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I need to write an WPF(4.0) application which has a DB but no tables in it. 
The app has to create some tables in the DB and then start working with them.
I am wondering , is there a way to do it in Linq to SQL ?

Comment: How could Linq *create* tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this programatically. i.e. You can create programatically your tables, according to given parameters, also it is possible to build the relations between tables... :)

As there is no direct function **create table**, you can use the `ExecuteCommand` -method of the `DataContext` to run some T-SQL statements for creating tables.

Comment: you mean ADO.NET , yes? yeah , I know it's can be generated programatically in ADO.NET but I was hoping that there is an option now to do it by LINQ to SQL...:)

Comment: N.D. To **Create a New Table** try this exemple: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C-Sharp#Create_a_New_Table   is an exemple of what I suggested you to do in my second part of response

Comment: Thanks , but I have seen that people have some troubles with that , have you tried this solution personally ? I will try it , but I wonder if it really works?